# How to force an RSpec test to fail?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

**What's the proper way to force an RSpec test to fail?**

I'm considering `1.should == 2` however there's probably something better.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

`fail`/`raise` will do the trick (they are aliases of each other).

#### Example

```
specify "this test fails" do
  raise "this is my failure message"
end
```

Fails with:

```
1) failing this test fails
   Failure/Error: raise "this is my failure message"

   RuntimeError:
     this is my failure message
```

### Alternatives

If you are thinking of using `raise`/`fail` in a spec, you should consider that there are probably more explicit ways of writing your expectation.

Additionally, `raise`/`fail` doesn't play well with [`aggregate_failures`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-9/docs/aggregating-failures) because the exception short-circuits the block and won't run any following matchers.

#### Mark a test as pending

If you need to mark a test as pending to make sure you get back to it, you could use the `fail`/`raise`, but you can also use [`pending`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-9/docs/pending-and-skipped-examples/pending-examples).

```
#  Instead of this:
it "should do something" do
   # ...
   raise "this needs to be implemented"
end

# ✅ Try this:
it "should do something" do
  pending "this needs to be implemented"
end
```

#### Assert that a block is not called

If you need to ensure a block is not being executed, consider using the [`yield` matchers](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-9/docs/built-in-matchers/yield-matchers). For example:

```
describe "Enumerable#any?" do
  #  Instead of this:
  it "doesn't yield to the block if the collection is empty" do
    [].any? { raise "it should not call this block" }
  end

  # ✅ Try this:
  it "doesn't yield to the block if the collection is empty" do
    expect { |b| [].any?(&b) }.not_to yield_control
  end
end
```

Comment: `fail` example: `it("is awesome") { fail "needs flamethrower" }`

Comment: I think in the latest version of rails / ruby you'd actually use `raise` instead of fail: `it("is does a") { raise "it should do b" }`

Comment: @frbl `raise` and `fail` are aliases. So, either works. It's a style decision whether to use one or the other.

Comment: This doesn't work with `aggregateFailures` — the exception breaks out of the block.

Comment: Thanks @DavidMoles! I updated the answer to include that caveat.

Answer (score 6):

I know that this was asked and answered many years ago, but `RSpec::ExampleGroups` has a `flunk` method. I prefer this `flunk` method to using `fail` in the context of testing. Using `fail` has an implied code failure (you can see more on that here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43424847/550454).

So, you can use:

```rb
it 'is expected to fail the test' do
  flunk 'explicitly flunking the test'
end
```

Comment: I believe this is actually in `Minitest::Assertions`, which is wrapped by `rspec-rails`, but not core `rspec`.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to simulate an RSpec expectation failure rather than an exception, the method you're looking for is [`RSpec::Expectations.fail_with`](https://rubydoc.info/github/rspec/rspec-expectations/main/RSpec%2FExpectations.fail_with):

```rb
describe 'something' do
  it "doesn't work" do
    RSpec::Expectations.fail_with('oops')
  end
end

# => oops
#
# 0) something doesn't work
#    Failure/Error: RSpec::Expectations.fail_with('oops')
#      oops
```

Note that despite the documentation, `fail_with` doesn't actually raise an `ExpectationNotMetError` directly, but rather passes it to the private method `RSpec::Support.notify_failure`. This is handy when using `aggregate_failures`, which (under the hood) works via a [custom failure notifier](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/blob/v3.10.0/lib/rspec/expectations/failure_aggregator.rb).

```rb
describe 'some things' do
  it "sometimes work" do
    aggregate_failures('things') do
      (0..3).each do |i|
        RSpec::Expectations.fail_with("#{i} is odd") if i.odd?
      end
    end
  end
end

# => some things
# 
# Got 2 failures from failure aggregation block "things":
# 
#   1) 1 is odd
# 
#   2) 3 is odd
# 
#   0) some things sometimes work
#      Got 2 failures from failure aggregation block "things".
# 
#      0.1) Failure/Error: RSpec::Expectations.fail_with("#{i} is odd") if i.odd?
#             1 is odd
# 
#      0.2) Failure/Error: RSpec::Expectations.fail_with("#{i} is odd") if i.odd?
#             3 is odd
#     sometimes work (FAILED - 1)
```