# Fail vs. raise in Ruby : Should we really believe the style guide?

Tags: ruby, exception, coding-style, conventions

Ruby offers two possibilities to cause an exception programmatically:  `raise` and `fail`, both being `Kernel` methods. According to the documents, they are absolutely equivalent.

Out of a habit, I used only `raise` so far. Now I found several recommendations (for example [here](https://www.relishapp.com/womply/ruby-style-guide/docs/exceptions)), to use `raise` for exceptions to be caught, and `fail` for serious errors which are not meant to be handled.

But does it really make sense? When you are writing a class or module, and cause a problem deep inside, which you signal by `fail`, your programming colleagues who are reviewing the code, might happily understand your intentions, but the person who is *using* my code will most likely not look at my code and has no way of knowing, whether the exception was caused by a `raise` or by `fail`. Hence, my careful usage of `raise` or `fail` can't have any influence on his decision, whether she should or should not handle it.

Could someone see flaws in my arguments? Or are there other criteria, which might me want to use `fail` instead of `raise`?

Comment: I think this question could be treated as off-topic, as it doesn't consist a specific problem, so in my opinion it is more suitable for example to [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @m.cekiera when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @m.cekiera: Actually, the problem arose from a specific problem (I am writing a library and want to raise an exception, when an argument passed to a method is out of range), but I thought that providing this information does not help answering the question. Thanks however for commenting.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

> use 'raise' for exceptions to be caught, and 'fail' for serious errors which are not meant to be handled

This is not what the [official style guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#exceptions) or the link you provided say on the matter.

What is meant here is use `raise` only in `rescue` blocks. Aka use `fail` when you want to say something is *failing* and use `raise` when *rethrowing* an exception.

As for the *"does it matter"* part - it is not one of the most hardcore strictly followed rules, but you could make the same argument for any convention. You should follow in that order:

1. Your project style guide
2. Your company style guide
3. The community style guide

Ideally, the three should be the same.

---

**Update**: As of [this PR](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide/issues/512) (December 2015), the convention is to always use `raise`.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this! This makes it clear to me (though I'm still somewhat puzzled about the usefulness of this rule, because I can in general easily see from the code, whether I am rethrowing an exception or not. As far I understand it, nothing is gained by additionally emphasizing this fact by using a different command.

Comment: @user1934428, it is just the right name for the right case. Also, imagine that you want to do slightly more processing that wraps the original exception (for example) in case of an error. Therefore, you might create a dedicated private method for that. It will be useful to see `raise` instead of `fail` there as the rethrowing wont be preceded by `rescue`.

Answer (score 17):

I once had a conversation with [Jim Weirich](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jim_Weirich) about this very thing, I have since always used `fail` when my method is explicitly failing for some reason and `raise` to re-thrown exceptions.

Here is a post with a message from Jim (almost verbatim to what he said to me in person):
http://www.virtuouscode.com/2014/05/21/jim-weirich-on-exceptions/

Here is the relevant text from the post, a quote attributed to Jim:

> Here’s my basic philosophy (and other random thoughts) on exceptions.
>
> When you call a method, you have certain expectations about what the method will accomplish. Formally, these expectations are called post-conditions. A method should throw an exception whenever it fails to meet its postconditions.
>
> To effectively use this strategy, it implies you must have a small understanding of Design by Contract and the meaning of pre- and post-conditions. I think that’s a good thing to know anyways.
>
> Here’s some concrete examples. The Rails model `save` method:
>
> ```
> model.save!
> -- post-condition: The model object is saved.
> ```
>
> If the model is not saved for some reason, then an exception must be raised because the post-condition is not met.
>
> ```
> model.save
> -- post-condition: (the model is saved && result == true) ||
>                    (the model is not saved && result == false)
> ```
>
> If `save` doesn’t actually save, then the returned result will be `false` , but the post-condition is still met, hence no exception.
>
> I find it interesting that the `save!` method has a vastly simpler post-condition.
>
> On the topic of rescuing exceptions, I think an application should have strategic points where exceptions are rescued. There is little need for rescue/rethrows for the most part. The only time you would want to rescue and rethrow is when you have a job half-way done and you want to undo something so avoid a partially complete state. Your strategic rescue points should be chosen carefully so that the program can continue with other work even if the current operation failed. Transaction processing programs should just move on to the next transaction. A Rails app should recover and be ready to handle the next http request.
>
> Most exception handlers should be generic. Since exceptions indicate a failure of some type, then the handler needs only make a decision on what to do in case of failure. Detailed recovery operations for very specific exceptions are generally discouraged unless the handler is very close (call graph wise) to the point of the exception.
>
> Exceptions should not be used for flow control, use `throw/catch` for that. This reserves exceptions for true failure conditions.
>
> (An aside, because I use exceptions to indicate failures, I almost always use the `fail` keyword rather than the `raise` keyword in Ruby. `Fail` and `raise` are synonyms so there is no difference except that `fail` more clearly communcates that the method has failed. The only time I use `raise` is when I am catching an exception and re-raising it, because here I’m *not* failing, but explicitly and purposefully raising an exception. This is a stylistic issue I follow, but I doubt many other people do).
>
> There you have it, a rather rambling memory dump on my thoughts on exceptions.

I know that there are many style guides that do not agree (the  [style guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#prefer-raise-over-fail) used by [RoboCop](http://rubocop.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), for example). I don't care. Jim convinced me.

Comment: Taken too early.  Thanks for sharing this answer of his.  Makes perfect sense.